# Solaris tcp_time_wait_interval configuration

Tags: tcp, solaris, httpserver

In my Solaris server, I have an HTTP Server which handle many incoming connections. In my server logic, it closes connection from client manually so that many TIME_WAIT status appear when I call command netstat -an in my server.

So that I change the tcp_time_wait_interval to 10 second with command:

> ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_time_wait_interval 10000

But I read from user guide, it says : "Do not set the value lower than 60 seconds".

Does anyone know why Oracle recommend that?

The user guide URL is : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-6779/chapter4-51/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Was told my Oracle engineer with a very heavy trans load in thousands/sec can set to as low as 10 ms on Solaris 11/11.1